# Query to get specific value between two table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two table which contains two different primary key, lets call them, **table1** and **table2**.

The tables may have the same number of columns.

Table1:

| ID | NOM | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 661YYYDD |
| 2 | BBB | YYYD661 |
| 3 | CCC | YD661 |
| 4 | DDD | P5500Z |

Table 2:

| ID | KEYCODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 661 |
| 2 | 55 |

I want to be able to get by KEYCODE:
ALL record in table1 which contain 661 or 55. For example when I select by 661 I get only the first 3 rows from tables1.

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE CODE LIKE '%661%'`?

Comment: @VvdL : Little different from that, which is between % must be a key code in another table which is table 2, i want to get all rows from table1  containing the  key code in table2.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Please check if my answer below works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.CODE LIKE '%'||TABLE2.KEYCODE||'%'
WHERE TABLE2.KEYCODE = '661'
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1f67fa2920ebeb333b5b5b173b27e396)